# How to Scrape a Drop Down Menu with RSelenium

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rselenium

I'd like to understand how to **scrape** a drop-down menu. I should be using xpath, but I don't know how to give the right line for the value I am interested in. Here are the lines of HTML we are talking about

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Sales channels</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <select id="source" name="source" data-placeholder="All sales channels" class="form-control select2 baloon-filter" multiple="multiple" data-filter-label="Channel:" data-search-button-id="smartSearchButton">
        
                <option value="4">WOOCOMMERCE</option>
                                
                <option value="6">EBAY UK</option>
                                
                <option value="8">EPRICE</option>
                                
                <option value="5">AMAZON UK</option>
                                
                <option value="3">FIND PRICE</option>
                                
                <option value="7">FACEBOOK SHOP</option>
                                
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using RSelenium. I think you more or less such a line

```
sales.channels <- remote_driver$findElement( using = 'xpath' , '//select[@id="source"]/option[@value="EBAY UK" ]'
sales.channels3$clickElement()
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me

Comment: @barny Ok now that it meets your grammar and tag standards, can you answer the question ????? Thank you

Comment: @phil Ok now that it meets your grammar and tag standards, can you answer the question ????? Thank you

Comment: I'm not clear on what URL you are attempting to scrape from, so I'm not able to help you. If you are trying to extract out of the HTML code you provided above, I would use regex, including tools from the `stringr` package, instead of `rselenium`.